# Printing contents of array LISP

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, lisp, common-lisp

Why does this code not print out the content of the array -

```
(defun loopfn (state)
       (loop for x from 0 to 2 do
        (loop for y from 0 to 2 do
             (aref state x y))))
```

Here I am passing a 3x3 matrix which is built like this -

```
`(setq i (make-array '(3,3) :initial-contents '((0 1 3) (4 2 5) (7 8 6))))`
```

I am calling - (loopfn i)

Edit--------
@Greg
Thanks for pointing that out...
I had the following question..
Why does this print the output ...

```
(defun loopfn ()
   (loop for x from 0 to 3 do
    (if (eq x 2)(return (list x)))))
```

Where as this prints a nil...

```
(defun loopfn ()
   (loop for x from 0 to 2 do
    (loop for y from 0 to 2 do
         (if (eq x 2)(return (list x y))))))
```

I am calling

```
(loopfn)
```

Comment: Did you forget the part that actually prints the output? Like `(print (aref ...))`?

Comment: @Greg Hewgill  Can you please clear the second part of my question...I edited it...

Comment: EQ is not for number comparison. Use EQL or =.

Comment: Hi! Did you know that if any of the answers has answered your question you can accept that answer by clicking an empty green outline of a V checkmark next to it. This will bump your reputation as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `aref` is getting the specified element, but you're not doing anything with it. You could stick it on to a list which is then returned:

```
(defun loopfn (state)
  (let ((result '()))
    (loop for x from 0 to 2 do
     (loop for y from 0 to 2 do
          (setf result (cons (aref state x y) result))))
   result))
```

or you could just print it out:

```
(defun loopfn (state)
  (loop for x from 0 to 2 do
       (loop for y from 0 to 2 do
        (format t "~a~%" (aref state x y)))))
```

The former is far more useful ; you want to return things which can then be further processed, and anything that gets passed to the top level will be printed out for you.

As long as you are using `LOOP` you can easily gather up your values with `COLLECT`, `APPEND`, etc., which is the idiomatic way to do it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info.......I modified my code.....                  defun loopfn (state target)
  (loop for x from 0 to 2
    do (loop for y from 0 to 2            
   do (if (eq (aref state x y) target) (princ (list x y))))))                                                                              But the output is like (2 1 ) Nil ... My question is how to output only the list (2 1) and not the nil....

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not print anything. That's also what you want - usually.

But you want functions to return something useful.

So you need to understand the difference between printing and having a REPL printing a return value.

```
CL-USER > 3
3
```

Above returns 3. The Read-Eval-Print-Loop prints the return value.

```
CL-USER > (print 3)

3 
3
```

Above prints a `newline` and then two times the `3`. Why?
The first is the side-effect of the `PRINT` call which prints the newline and then its argument.
The second is the REPL printing the return value.

Note also the `EQ` is not for numeric comparisons. Use `EQL` instead.
See: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_eql.htm

Answer (score 2):

As for your second question, `(return ...)` is equivalent to `(return-from NIL ...)` so you just return from your inner `LOOP` into the outer one. Use this instead:

```
[11]> (defun loopfn () 
        (loop for x from 0 to 2 do 
          (loop for y from 0 to 2 do 
            (if (= x 2) (return-from loopfn (list x y))))))
[12]> (loopfn)
(2 0)
```

Another possibility is to collect more values than just one, as in

```
[36]> (defun loopfn ()
        (loop for x from 0 to 2 nconc 
          (loop for y from 0 to 2 
                if (= y 2) 
                collect (list x y))) )
LOOPFN
[37]> (loopfn)
((0 2) (1 2) (2 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

This was neatly covered in [this forum topic](http://www.lispforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1313).

> The outer loop has no clause which would cause a return value.

Some code examples from that thread:

```
(defun print-2d-array-as-table (array)
  (loop for i from 0 below (array-dimension array 0)
    do (loop for j from 0 below (array-dimension array 1)
             do (princ (aref array i j))
                (if (= j (1- (array-dimension array 1)))
                    (terpri)
                    (princ #\Space)))))
```

and one loop:

```
(defun print-2d-array-as-table (array)
  (loop for i below (array-total-size array) do
    (if (zerop (mod i (array-dimension array 0)))
      (terpri)
      (princ #\Space))
    (princ (row-major-aref array i))))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the link.......I modified my code.....                  defun loopfn (state target)
  (loop for x from 0 to 2
    do (loop for y from 0 to 2            
   do (if (eq (aref state x y) target) (princ (list x y))))))                                                                              But the output is like (2 1 ) Nil ... My question is how to output only the list (2 1) and not the nil....

Comment: By default, something has to be returned, even if it's just `nil`, but  if you call `(values)`, it returns nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, in the loop that doesn't print, `(eq x 2)` is never true. You have modified the loop bounds from `0 to 3` to `0 to 2`, so `x` never reaches `2`. Since there is no explicit `(return ...)` executed, the function returns `nil`.

Comment: That's "0 to 2", not "from 0 below 2", try (loop for x from 0 to 2 collect x) and see what values X get inside the loop.