# How to make zeros matrix and set specific item to one with LISP

Tags: arrays, lisp, common-lisp

I try to make two dimensional matrix with zeros and after i need set some items to one

i tried:

> `(defun my_array ()
>       (setq x (make-array '(5 5)))
>       (setf (aref x 3 3) 1)
>       (setf (aref x 3 4) 1)
>       (setf (aref x 3 1) 1)
>       (setf (aref x 3 2) 1)
>   )`

and i call it with main function:

> `(defun main ()
>     (my_array)
>   )`

but its doesn't work. Task for my code is:

> `34 > (step (main))`

`((0 0 0 0 0) (0 0 0 0 0)) 
 ((0 0 0 0 0) (0 0 0 0 0)) 
 ((0 0 0 0 0) (0 0 0 0 0)) 
 NIL`

Can anybody tell me, where's mistake and how can i do it correct? I need universally way, because i need matrix of 20x20 and now i try to learn operate with matrix

Comment: Your `my_array` function should return `1`, since the the last form is `(setf ... 1)`.  How are you get array output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CL-USER 1 > (let ((array (make-array '(5 5) :initial-element 0)))
              (setf (aref array 0 0) 1)
              array)
#2A((1 0 0 0 0) (0 0 0 0 0) (0 0 0 0 0) (0 0 0 0 0) (0 0 0 0 0))
```

Comment: And is any way to print separately lines? I think same x index on one line.

Comment: @DavidK.Haas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254825/printing-contents-of-array-lisp